# How to exactly know what a PowerShell(PS) command really did

Tags: powershell

For example, for the default/built-in commands like `Set-AzureVMCustomScriptExtension` ([document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722462.aspx)), how to find what really happened when the command does not work? 
In my case, there is no error posted after execution of this command, but it just does not work: I want to run a script, say `ScriptA`, in the command 
`Set-AzureVMCustomScriptExtension -Run $ScriptA` (Other parameters are all correctly set up). 
The `ScriptA` did not run at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual code you are using, along with any input it is receiving. Asking us to explain why your code isn't working when we can't see your code is a NOP.

Answer (score 1):

1. That's a cmdlet for the Azure-module, not a built-in "default" cmdlet.
2. Read the error message. When a cmdlet fails it returns an `ErrorRecord` object that explains what went wrong, ex. "Access denied". If you want to know the values used for he parameters at that time, you have to output them during the script using ex. `Write-Verbose`, `Write-Debug` or use PowerShell ISE to run the script with some breakpoints so you can watch your variables when the error is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. In my case, no error posted after execution. But `ScriptA` does not run at all. Please see my edited post for more reference.

Comment: You need to update the question with the full command and sample-values. I have no idea what `$scriptA` contains. Use `-verbose` and `-debug` to see if it outputs  anything

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the cmdlet as below with `Verbose` and `Debug` switch to view what happens behind the scene with the cmdlet:

```
Set-AzureVMCustomScriptExtension -Run $ScriptA -Verbose -Debug
```

If it runs correctly then you will have to troubleshoot the script from the Azure VM. Then the error has nothing to do with this cmdlet. Check if the script is getting set as custom script extension with the VM. Check if the script has any bug in the logic.